# Whats the meaning of ] symbol in a SQL query?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I have come across a CTF challenge that has a part with an SQL injection (MySQL DB). I have completed it, but I do not know why or how the injection works.
The query in the PHP application would probably be like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'admin@admin.sys' AND password = md5('1234');
```

And the injection code I entered in the text field :

```
xxx@xxx.xxx' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1 -- ' ]
```

Would probably result in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.xxx' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1 -- ' ] AND password = md5('1234');
```

It doesn't work without the `]`, but I do not understand the use of `]` here. Please explain it to me!

Comment: Is the `]` necessary?  The `--` is an SQL comment, so theoretically nothing after that should matter anyway.  Naively, I would expect this to work equally well without the `]`

Comment: Is it to circumvent some very low-class validation? For example, a regex that filters out input that ends with the normal `--`. Are there any other characters that work in place of `]`?

Comment: So it doesnt work if your remove ], but does it work if you replace it with something else lika a X?

Comment: It works even if I completely remove xxx@xxx.xxx and LIMIT 1. But doesn't work without ]

Comment: `]` is the delimiter for tokens-used-as-identifiers (that is, a table named `[Table]` or similar) and strict casing/whitespace in SQL Server.  Perhaps the filter was intended to work for SQL Server?  I can't check whether `--` would be valid in a table name at the moment.